# WPF passing a button in t a c# function

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a form that has a lot of buttons in it.

Each button does almost the same thing.

1. checks a bool to see the state of the button
2. sends a command based on the state.
3. changes the background of the button to reflect the state
4. resets bool to correct state.

```
 private void button_DSK1_LowerThird_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (button_DSK1_LowerThird_Click== false)

        {

            string newmessage = server.TCPmessage(Vars.ComandSDK1LowerThird);
            string dataReturn = server.Connect(Vars.IPAdress, 5250, newmessage);
            textBlock_output.Text = dataReturn.ToString();

            if (dataReturn.Contains("202"))
            {

                button_DSK1_LowerThird_State = true;
                Uri resourceUri = new Uri("white-glossy-lit.png", UriKind.Relative);
                StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(resourceUri);

                BitmapFrame temp = BitmapFrame.Create(streamInfo.Stream);
                var brush = new ImageBrush();
                brush.ImageSource = temp;

                button_DSK1_LowerThird.Background = brush;


            }
            else
            {

                button_DSK1_LowerThird_State = false;

                Uri resourceUri = new Uri("white-glossy-rectangle-button-md.png", UriKind.Relative);
                StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(resourceUri);

                BitmapFrame temp = BitmapFrame.Create(streamInfo.Stream);
                var brush = new ImageBrush();
                brush.ImageSource = temp;

                button_DSK1_LowerThird.Background = brush;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string newmessage = server.TCPmessage("CG 1-20 STOP 1");
            string dataReturn = server.Connect(Vars.IPAdress, 5250, newmessage);
            textBlock_output.Text = dataReturn.ToString();

            if (dataReturn.Contains("202"))
            {

                button_DSK1_LowerThird_State = false;
                Uri resourceUri = new Uri("white-glossy-rectangle-button-md.png", UriKind.Relative);
                StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(resourceUri);

                BitmapFrame temp = BitmapFrame.Create(streamInfo.Stream);
                var brush = new ImageBrush();
                brush.ImageSource = temp;

                button_DSK1_LowerThird.Background = brush;


            }
            else
            {

                button_DSK1_LowerThird_State = true;

                Uri resourceUri = new Uri("white-glossy-lit.png", UriKind.Relative);
                StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(resourceUri);

                BitmapFrame temp = BitmapFrame.Create(streamInfo.Stream);
                var brush = new ImageBrush();
                brush.ImageSource = temp;

                button_DSK1_LowerThird.Background = brush;
            }
        }
```

I have all this working correctly. Instead of copying and pasting it a bunch of times I want to move all the code inside of button_DSK1_LowerThird_Click to a function.
I can then call that function and not coppy and paste all the code 25 times.
I can do that.  what i can not figure out how to do in the function is.
this line `button_DSK1_LowerThird.Background = brush;`

what do i need to pass in to the function to replace button_DSK1_LowerThird?

when i call the function i thought, at least in my brain, i could call it like so

```
ButtonState(string command, Button button, bool state);
```

then i could have my function check and do every thing that needs to happen for that button. 
this is my function as i have it.

```
 public void ButtonState(string command, Button button, bool state)
    {
        CasparCG server = new CasparCG();

        if (state == false)

        {

            string newmessage = server.TCPmessage(command);
            string dataReturn = server.Connect(Vars.IPAdress, 5250, newmessage);

            if (dataReturn.Contains("202"))
            {

                state = true;
                Uri resourceUri = new Uri("white-glossy-lit.png", UriKind.Relative);
                StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(resourceUri);

                BitmapFrame temp = BitmapFrame.Create(streamInfo.Stream);
                var brush = new ImageBrush();
                brush.ImageSource = temp;

                button.Background = brush;


            }
            else
            {

                state = false;

                Uri resourceUri = new Uri("white-glossy-rectangle-button-md.png", UriKind.Relative);
                StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(resourceUri);

                BitmapFrame temp = BitmapFrame.Create(streamInfo.Stream);
                var brush = new ImageBrush();
                brush.ImageSource = temp;

                button.Background = brush;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string newmessage = server.TCPmessage("CG 1-20 STOP 1");
            string dataReturn = server.Connect(Vars.IPAdress, 5250, newmessage);


            if (dataReturn.Contains("202"))
            {

                state = false;
                Uri resourceUri = new Uri("white-glossy-rectangle-button-md.png", UriKind.Relative);
                StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(resourceUri);

                BitmapFrame temp = BitmapFrame.Create(streamInfo.Stream);
                var brush = new ImageBrush();
                brush.ImageSource = temp;

                button.Background = brush;


            }
            else
            {

                state = true;

                Uri resourceUri = new Uri("white-glossy-lit.png", UriKind.Relative);
                StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(resourceUri);

                BitmapFrame temp = BitmapFrame.Create(streamInfo.Stream);
                var brush = new ImageBrush();
                brush.ImageSource = temp;

                button.Background = brush;
            }
        }
```

i am newer to coding i know there are better ways to do this,  i just have not learned them yet.

Comment: Just use a ToggleButton https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please take the help->tour, your question is vauge, shows no code for us to help you with. After you've taken the tour, show us your code, and explain why you need our help

Answer (score 1):

Have a single click event for all buttons and typecast Sender to button and based on button you can carryout your function.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is Button)
            {
                var btn = sender as Button;
                // Here you can carry out  your functionality
            }           
        }
```